# how to hide span class but keep it's space

Tags: javascript

check the statement below:

L1: HEY . YOU

`<div>L1:<span class="lang1"> HEY </span> . <span class="lang1"> YOU</span> </div>`

if I use this jQuery below

```
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        $(".lang1").hide();
    });
});
```

it will hide HEY and YOU but it would then SHIFT THE . SEPARATOR TO THE LEFT when they hide. 
how can I edit this to hide HEY and YOU but with keeping their spaces so that the . separator remain still in the middle. I kinda think it has something to load a CSS class that is set to visibility:hidden / just not sure how to implement this / help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set opacity to 0 in css with a class and use js to set this class to the span.

```
.lang1.opacity0{
   opacity:0; 
}
```

In JS

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".lang1").addClass('opacity0');
});
```

When you add class "opacity0" to the span it will now aplly the styles I entioned at the first.

Or hide text but with underscores using different class strategy applied with the same Jquery code:

```
.lang1.hidewithunderscore{
    color:transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid #222;
}
```

In JS

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".lang1").addClass('hidewithunderscore');
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify on how this can be done on the JS code? I’m a beginner:)

Comment: I’ll try that now, and one more question, if you can help.. what If I wanted to display “_____” . _____” ... how can I display under scores for the empty spaces, instead of opacity zero ?

Comment: Code updatedm just need to apply different class strategy